# How can I use outer loop index in inner loop

Tags: handlebars.js

This is first time I am playing with `HandleBars.js`.I have an array in the following way.

```
var arr=[[a,b,c],[d],[e,f],[g,h,i,j]];
```

I want to get in the following way.

for first iteration time:

```
  biz0_a0;
  biz0_a1;
  biz0_a2;
```

second Iteration:

```
  biz1_a0;
```

third Iteration :

```
 biz2_a0;
 biz2_a1;
```

fourth Iteration:

```
biz3_a0;
biz3_a1;
biz3_a2;
biz3_a3;
```

so If you observe, I want to use outer loop,inner loop indexes inside inner loop. I can able to find inner loop using `{{@index}}` so wherever I want inner loop index I am using `{{@index}}`. in the same way I can't able to use outer loop index inside inner loop.I tried  like `{{../@index}}`.So I did in the following way.

```
biz{{../@index}}_a{{@index}}.
```

it's not working.

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: It should be `{{@../index}}`. See: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration